# How to dynamically add an ondragstart event to a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

There are a couple of questions that seem to ask this question, but no one accepted answers and nothing has worked for me.

I have a 'group' button that when it's clicked, will dynamically create a 'group' div (I then append some pre-selected 'child' divs within it)
However I need the new 'group' div to be draggable.
I can set the draggable attribute dynamically, no problem.
But being draggable is not much good without the `ondragstart()` event, and no matter what I've tried, I can't get this assigned.
I am using jQuery which may have a bearing.

The latest iteration of my code is (this appears in an `init()` function that is called from `body.onload`):

```
var group=$(document.createElement('div'));
group.attr({id: 'group'+grpcount});
group.attr({draggable: "true"});
group.addClass('group');
group.html("<span class='group'>Group"+grpcount+"</span>");
$('#boundary').append(group);   
document.getElementById('group'+grpcount).addEventListener("startdrag",drag);
```

But I have also tried various combinations of jQuery `.bind`:

```
group.bind("dragstart", drag(ev));
group.bind("dragstart", function(ev){drag(ev);});
```

All to no avail.

I have a drag function already defined (and I've tried putting it before and after the code above):

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id+":"+ev.pageX+":"+ev.pageY);
}
```

I hope there is something glaringly obvious that I just can't see.
Can somebody solve this?

Comment: `group.bind("dragstart", function(ev){drag(ev);});`  should work fine. As should `group.bind("dragstart", drag);`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/K4hgw/.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this:

```
function drag(ev) {  alert('Hi');  }

var grpcount = 21;
var group=$(document.createElement('div'));
group.attr({id: 'group'+grpcount});
group.attr({draggable: "true"});
group.addClass('group');
group.html("<span class='group'>Group"+grpcount+"</span>");
group.bind("dragstart", function(ev){drag(ev);});
$('#boundary').append(group);
```

See the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nxcSz/

Comment: Thanks, seeing your fiddle work helped me persist, I can now prove the event call is working, my problem actually is that ev.dataTransfer is undefined  (only seems to be a problem on dynamically attached event handler - when I statically define a group and attach the handler in the HTML it all behaves as expected).  I suspect that using jQuery throughout is going to be my only way around this so will explore some of the content that @Armen has pointed at.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be better to take a look at Jquery UI draggable [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

and if you dont know yet, you can call multiple jquery finctions in a chain, so your code looks more readable like below:

```
var group=$('div').attr('id', 'group'+grpcount)
                  .addClass('group')
                  .html("<span class='group'>Group"+grpcount+"</span>");

$('#boundary').append(group);
```

and instead of

```
document.getElementById('group'+grpcount).addEventListener("startdrag",drag);
```

use this

```
group.draggable({
    start:function(event, ui){
         //this is where dragging starts when you push mousedown and move mouse
    },
    drag:function(event, ui){
         //this function will be called after drag started each time you move your mouse
    }
    stop:function(event, ui){
         //this is where you release mouse button
    }
})
```

this jquery draggable widget with [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) widget will ease your life if you really want to implement complex drag-and-drop functionality

Comment: Good to know on jQuery structure.  In the end I did this: `var group=$(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'group'+grpcount)   .addClass('group')   .html("<span class='group'>Group"+grpcount+"</span>");`  Otherwise it applied the changes to all my 'div's.  I have tried the group.draggable() approach, but get an error "group.draggable is not a function" (I added in the odd , and ; that I assumed should be there but still same error).  Must be something to do with the scope/de-referencing of group somehow? I shall explore more around jQuery UI to learn more.  Thanks for help.

Comment: Ah, I am only including Jquery, not JQuery UI (doh!), will get onto that and retest...

Comment: Yes, that worked, as with Robert R solution, shifts the problem to ev.dataTransfer not being defined.  So technically you have both answered the original question but don't think I can multi-select correct answers.